# Missing characters in console after CTRL+C break handler

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm encountering a situation where I have a loop displaying the progress of a process.  This can be interrupted with a ConsoleCancelEventHandler where the user can press CTRL+C to interrupt the process.  Upon interruption, or breaking out of the loop, not all the output from Console.Write appears in the console.  In this one case the first character does not print.  Does anyone know what am I doing wrong.

```
class Program
{
    static bool userCancelled = false;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.CancelKeyPress += new ConsoleCancelEventHandler(handler);
        Console.WriteLine("Press CTRL+C/BREAK to break loop, Escape to stop execution, Enter to continue");
        string theChars = "Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog";
        while (true)
        {
            char[] carray = theChars.ToCharArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < carray.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(i, 1);
                Console.Write(carray[i]);
            }
                
            Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth - Console.CursorLeft));
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 2);
            Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth - Console.CursorLeft));


            if (userCancelled)
            {
                ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey();
                if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                    userCancelled = false;
                else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
                {
                    userCancelled = true;
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 1);
                    Console.Write(theChars);
                    Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth - Console.CursorLeft));
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 2);
                    Console.Write("Q is missing, why?");
                    Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth - Console.CursorLeft));
                    break;
                }
                else
                    userCancelled = false;
            }
        }

    }
    static void handler(object handler, ConsoleCancelEventArgs args)
    {
        
        userCancelled = args.Cancel = true;
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 2);
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.Write($"You pressed {args.SpecialKey}");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth - Console.CursorLeft));
    }
}
```

[Here's the console output after user cancels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSMWZ.png)

Comment: Can you explain what this code is supposed to do? The implementation is probably wrong and you have *race condition*: setting `userCancelled` in `handler()` will be very likely ignored.

Comment: Typically ctrl+c is used to *break* (stop completely), it seems you are trying to implement pause/resume? Then use handler to exit software and some other key to pause.

Comment: The `carray` loop is simulating the progress of the process, which can be paused and resumed with the `ConsoleCancelEventHandler`.  When the user presses Escape key to terminate the loop, the `Console.Write` doesn't print all that is sent.

Comment: @BAbbasi you code has statement `if (userCancelled)`. `userCancelled` is set to `false` at startup. That means with that code, codes into infinite loop. Are you sure this is the code that causes the problem you are describing? If not, could you update the question with correct code?

Comment: @vish it is supposed to be an infinite loop.  User is supposed to hit CTRL-C to pause it and hit escape to break out of the infinite loop.  It's the ouptut from `Console.Write` after escape that does not appear on the screen properly.

Comment: @BAbbasi I meant infinite loop as in, it won't stop. I do not have screen record software and even if I did I don't know I could upload video. Remove that one statement keep remaining code as it is, and see what happens. There was no missing character in my case.

Comment: @vish, When I hit CTRL+C, I set the `userCancelled` to true, hit escape and the program terminates, as intended.  You don't see that behavior?

Comment: @BAbbasi see my answer below for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question: The reason why you have `Q` disappearing is because of statement `Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 1);`. [Console.SetCursorPosition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.setcursorposition?view=net-5.0) doc says it's zero based position and yet your statement causes it to behave this way. If you change the statement to `Console.SetCursorPosition(1, 1);` you no longer has that problem.

The best reason I can think of is when you press an `<Esc>`, it seem to behave like `<Backspace>`.

As for iterations, I have given slightly modified your code to denote how many iterations are actually happening if you keep `if (userCancelled)`. See below.

Here is the explanation why:

- You set `Console.CancelKeyPress` handler. That is a callback. Framework will call it when you press `Ctrl + Break`
- You have a call to `Console.ReadKey()` but that is **inside** `if (userCancelled)` block. `Console.ReadKey()`is the call that blocks and *waits*.
- Without call to `Console.ReadKey()`, program has nothing to do but loop.
- if user presses `Ctrl + C`, then you set `userCancelled` to `true`. That is the first time when `Console.ReadKey()` will be called.
- Once you press `Esc`, that is when you get out.

```
class Program
{
    static bool userCancelled = false;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.CancelKeyPress += new ConsoleCancelEventHandler(handler);
        Console.WriteLine("Press CTRL+C/BREAK to break loop, Escape to stop execution, Enter to continue");
        string theChars = "Quick Brown Fox Jumps Over The Lazy Dog";
        long iterations = 0L;
        while (true)
        {
            iterations++;
            char[] carray = theChars.ToCharArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < carray.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(i, 1);
                Console.Write(carray[i]);
            }
            Console.Write(" Iterations: " + iterations);
                
            Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth - Console.CursorLeft));
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 2);
            Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth - Console.CursorLeft));


            if (userCancelled)
            {
                ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey();
                if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
                    userCancelled = false;
                else if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
                {
                    userCancelled = true;
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(1, 1);
                    Console.Write(theChars);
                    Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth - Console.CursorLeft));
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 2);
                    Console.Write("Q is missing, why?");
                    Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth - Console.CursorLeft));
                    break;
                }
                else
                    userCancelled = false;
            }
        }

    }
    static void handler(object handler, ConsoleCancelEventArgs args)
    {
        
        userCancelled = args.Cancel = true;
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 2);
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.Write($"You pressed {args.SpecialKey}");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth - Console.CursorLeft));
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The `Console.SetCursorPosition` is used with zero as the x component throughout this program and behaves properly in every case except when the `<Esc>` is read through `Console.ReadKey()`.  I haven't used the really lengthy progress code here but, I have seen instances where up to 3 characters go missing from the start of the output string.  Which is what I was trying to get to the bottom off.